# How to run a job array in R using the rscript command from the command line?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, cluster-computing, hpc, slurm

I am wondering how I might be able to run 500 parallel jobs in `R` using the `Rscript` function. I currently have an `R` file that has the header on top:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
B <- as.numeric(args[1])
Num.Cores <- as.numeric(args[2])
```

Outside of the R file, I wish to pass which of the 500 jobs are to be run, which is specified by `B`. Also, I would like to control the number of cores/CPUs available to each job, `Num.Cores`.

I am wondering if there is software or guides that can allow this. I currently have a CentOS 7/Linux server and I know one way is to install Slurm. However, it is quite a hassle and I was wondering if there might be a way to execute 500 jobs, with a queue. Thanks.

Comment: Question is too broad. Easiest solution that I would go for: use `future` to parallelize; divide your jobs into `N` batches of size `X` (`X` how many jobs you can execute at a time). Iterate using two loops - inner is parallelized over multiple jobs and outer is for batches.

Comment: Controlling the number of cores is not something (I believe) that R is good at. That is, it either uses 1 or as many as it can get (when the matrix libraries allow), nothing else. This would require doing it externally to R, whether using [`cpulimit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cpulimit.1.html) or a VM of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would setup on a cluster using `SLURM` scheduler

1. `slurm` `sbatch` job submission script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   #SBATCH --partition=xxx             ### Partition (like a queue in PBS)
   #SBATCH --job-name=array_example    ### Job Name
   #SBATCH -o jarray.%j.%N.out         ### File in which to store job output/error
   #SBATCH --time=00-00:30:00          ### Wall clock time limit in Days-HH:MM:SS
   #SBATCH --nodes=1                   ### Node count required for the job
   #SBATCH --ntasks=1                  ### Nuber of tasks to be launched per Node
   #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2           ### Number of threads per task (OMP threads)
   #SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL            ### When to send mail
   #SBATCH --mail-user=xxx@gmail.com
   #SBATCH --get-user-env              ### Import your user environment setup
   #SBATCH --requeue                   ### On failure, requeue for another try
   #SBATCH --verbose                   ### Increase informational messages
   #SBATCH --array=1-500%50            ### Array index | %50: number of simultaneously tasks

   echo
   echo "****************************************************************************"
   echo "*                                                                          *"
   echo "********************** sbatch script for array job *************************"
   echo "*                                                                          *"
   echo "****************************************************************************"
   echo

   current_dir=${PWD##*/}
   echo "Current dir: $current_dir"
   echo
   pwd
   echo

   # First we ensure a clean running environment:
   module purge

   # Load R
   module load R/R-3.5.0

   ### Initialization
   # Get Array ID
   i=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}

   # Output file
   outFile="output_parameter_${i}.txt"

   # Pass line #i to a R script 
   Rscript --vanilla my_R_script.R ${i} ${outFile}

   echo
   echo '******************** FINISHED ***********************'
   echo
   ```
2. `my_R_script.R` that takes `arg` from the `sbatch` script

   ```
   args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
   str(args)
   cat(args, sep = "\n")

   # test if there is at least one argument: if not, return an error
   if (length(args) == 0) {
     stop("At least one argument must be supplied (input file).\n", call. = FALSE)
   } else if (length(args) == 1) {
     # default output file
     args[2] = "out.txt"
   }

   cat("\n")
   print("Hello World !!!")

   cat("\n")
   print(paste0("i = ", as.numeric(args[1])))
   print(paste0("outFile = ", args[2]))

   ### Parallel:
   # https://hpc.nih.gov/apps/R.html
   # https://github.com/tobigithub/R-parallel/blob/gh-pages/R/code-setups/Install-doSNOW-parallel-DeLuxe.R

   # load doSnow and (parallel for CPU info) library
   library(doSNOW)
   library(parallel)   

   detectBatchCPUs <- function() { 
       ncores <- as.integer(Sys.getenv("SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK")) 
       if (is.na(ncores)) { 
           ncores <- as.integer(Sys.getenv("SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE")) 
       } 
       if (is.na(ncores)) { 
           return(2) # default
       } 
       return(ncores) 
   }

   ncpus <- detectBatchCPUs() 
   # or ncpus <- future::availableCores()
   cat(ncpus, " cores detected.")

   cluster = makeCluster(ncpus)

   # register the cluster
   registerDoSNOW(cluster)

   # get info
   getDoParWorkers(); getDoParName();

   ##### insert parallel computation here #####

   # stop cluster and remove clients
   stopCluster(cluster); print("Cluster stopped.")

   # insert serial backend, otherwise error in repetitive tasks
   registerDoSEQ()

   # clean up a bit.
   invisible(gc); remove(ncpus); remove(cluster); 

   # END
   ```

P.S: if you want to read a parameter file line by line, include the following line in the `sbatch` script then pass them to `my_R_script.R`

```
    ### Parameter file to read 
    parameter_file="parameter_file.txt"
    echo "Parameter file: ${parameter_file}"
    echo

    # Read line #i from the parameter file
    PARAMETERS=$(sed "${i}q;d" ${parameter_file})
    echo "Parameters are: ${PARAMETERS}"
    echo
```

Refs:

- http://tuxette.nathalievilla.org/?p=1696
- https://hpc.nih.gov/apps/R.html
- https://github.com/tobigithub/R-parallel/blob/gh-pages/R/code-setups/Install-doSNOW-parallel-DeLuxe.R