# HPC cluster: select the number of CPUs and threads in SLURM sbatch

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, slurm

The terminology used in the `sbatch` man page might be a bit confusing. Thus, I want to be sure I am getting the options set right. Suppose I have a task to run on a single node with N threads.  Am I correct to assume that I would use `--nodes=1` and `--ntasks=N`?

I am used to thinking about using, for example, pthreads to create N threads within a single process.  Is the result of that what they refer to as "cores" or "cpus per task"?  CPUs and threads are not the same things in my mind.

Comment: What would happen if --cpus-per-task exceed the #CPUs per node

Comment: I suppose nothing @V.ben as if you set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to a number greater than the number of cores on your machine. They will simply be "overloaded", but any additional clarification would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[Depending on the parallelism you are using: distributed or shared memory](https://research.computing.yale.edu/support/hpc/user-guide/slurm)

> `--ntasks=#`             : Number of "tasks" (use with distributed parallelism).
>
> `--ntasks-per-node=#`  : Number of "tasks" per node (use with distributed parallelism).
>
> `--cpus-per-task=#`      : Number of CPUs allocated to each task (use with shared memory parallelism).

---

[**From this question**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slurm-users/r_MNRw4gYhQ): if every node has 24 cores, is there any difference between these commands?

```
sbatch --ntasks 24 [...]
sbatch --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 24 [...]
```

[**Answer**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/slurm-users/r_MNRw4gYhQ/k0vmA6QOCwAJ): (by Matthew Mjelde)

> Yes there is a difference between those two submissions. You are correct that usually **`ntasks` is for `mpi` and `cpus-per-task` is for multithreading**, but let’s look at your commands:
>
> For your first example, the `sbatch --ntasks 24 […]` will allocate a job with 24 tasks.  These tasks in this case are only 1 CPUs, but may be split across multiple nodes. So you get a total of 24 CPUs across multiple nodes.
>
> For your second example, the `sbatch --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 24 [...]` will allocate a job with 1 task and 24 CPUs for that task.  Thus you will get a total of 24 CPUs on a single node.
>
> In other words, a task cannot be split across multiple nodes. **Therefore, using `--cpus-per-task` will ensure it gets allocated to the same node, while using `--ntasks` can and may allocate it to multiple nodes.**

---

[**Another good Q&A from CÉCI's support website**](http://www.ceci-hpc.be/slurm_faq.html#Q05): Suppose you need 16 cores. Here are some use cases:

> - you use mpi and do not care about where those cores are distributed: `--ntasks=16`
> - you want to launch 16 independent processes (no communication): `--ntasks=16`
> - you want those cores to spread across distinct nodes: `--ntasks=16 and --ntasks-per-node=1` or `--ntasks=16 and --nodes=16`
> - you want those cores to spread across distinct nodes and no interference from other jobs: `--ntasks=16 --nodes=16 --exclusive`
> - you want 16 processes to spread across 8 nodes to have two processes per node: `--ntasks=16 --ntasks-per-node=2`
> - you want 16 processes to stay on the same node: `--ntasks=16 --ntasks-per-node=16`
> - you want one process that can use 16 cores for multithreading: `--ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=16`
> - you want 4 processes that can use 4 cores each for multithreading: `--ntasks=4 --cpus-per-task=4`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in your example `sbatch --ntasks 24 […]`, what if I choose '--nodes=1' ? is it in this case will be same as your second example `sbatch --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 24 [...]`  which will get a total of 24 CPUs on a single node?

Comment: For your question: you will need `--nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=N` where N is the # of (OpenMP) parallel threads. See example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654725/786542

Comment: Is `sbatch --ntasks 1` indicates to the number of threads in the sbatch script?

Comment: No. The `--cpus-per-task=N` is

Comment: Does your last comment (about OpenMP) apply when no OpenMP is in use, just pthreads?

Comment: does `#SBATCH --nodes=N` (`N` higher the better) have any impact on this explanation?