# Sbatch resouce allocation for mult-threaded application

Tags: multithreading, scheduling, slurm, job-scheduling

After reading the very informative post, [HPC cluster: select the number of CPUs and threads in SLURM sbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139711/hpc-cluster-select-the-number-of-cpus-and-threads-in-slurm-sbatch/51141287#51141287), I understand the difference b/w the `--ntasks`, `--cpus-per-task` and `--ntasks-per-node` flags for sbatch.

My multi-threaded 'shared-memory' application is main command for my job execution. Sample script below,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -J test_job 
#SBATCH -t 01:00:00
#SBATCH -A project
#SBATCH -D /opt/
#SBATCH --ntasks=16
#SBATCH --nodes=1

cd model/

./a.out -parasol 16 -f input.dat
```

My question is

---

1. Whats the difference b/w the following combinations w.r.t. `sbatch` ?

> --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 16

> --ntasks 16 --nodes 1

---

2. Which of the above is the best/correct way to allocate resources for a multi-threaded (shared-memory) application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no difference between `--ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 16` and `--ntasks 16 --nodes 1` in terms of **CPU allocation**. Both will end up with 16 CPUs on the same node.

There will be difference though in the **environment** setup by Slurm for your job, among other, obviously, the values of `$SLURM_NTASKS` and `$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK`. This could have an impact on your job if `./a.out` uses those variables to decided on the number of threads to spawn. Or if `./a.out` uses the value of the `$OMP_NUM_THREADS` and that variable is set automatically by Slurm in the prolog to be equal to `$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK` (some clusters are configured that way).

There will also be a difference on the CPU **placement** if you use the `--distribution` option, or other related options.