# How to ask SLURM scheduler for CPUs on the same socket/NUMA node?

Tags: mpi, slurm

I am using a cluster where each node has 2 sockets, on each there is a CPU with 64 cores. My job scaling suggest me my job should use at most 64 cores. I repeatedly encounter the issue that, sometimes the job scheduler give me 48 cores on one socket, and 16 on the other, or some even more weird configurations. This ended up with significant loss of performance. I would like to force SLURM to give me CPUs on the same socket or NUMA node, or I would rather just wait for the resource to be availabvle.

I am using sbatch to submit the jobs. I checked the document that in srun you can designate cpu bindings, but I am not sure if you can tell the scheduler to do so when using sbatch.

To my understanding, the --bind-to arguments in mpirun does not help, as mpirun can only see the resources SLURM allocates you.

I have tried options like sockets-per-node and --threads-per-socket=64. But these only applied to node selection and are only a minimum. So if a node has a socket with at least 64 cores it will assign that node to me (which is the case for my cluster). I do not know how to coordinate resources in a finer way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139711/hpc-cluster-select-the-number-of-cpus-and-threads-in-slurm-sbatch discusses this at some length.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `sbatch` script settings this may depend on the specific SLURM configuration.

See: https://slurm.schedmd.com/cpu_management.html#Example15

```
#slurm.conf

SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core,CR_CORE_DEFAULT_DIST_BLOCK
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
```

srun command

```
srun --ntasks=3 --cpus-per-task=3 --ntasks-per-node=1 --cpu-bind=cores
```