# Running Rscript using qsub still using old version

Tags: r, sungridengine

I just want to run R-3.3.3.
if I ran on at local machine and execute sessionInfo() it shows that I ran using R-3.3.3.

but if I ran using qsub -V Rscript tes.sh 
it is shown that I use R-3.2.1

and i just ran qstat -j  
it is shown that I use the correct PATH ( R-3.3.3)

how does this happen? any suggestion for troubleshooting this?

Comment: from the terminal, run `module avail` then see what R versions are available on your cluster. After that include the line to call the available R version in your `qsub` script .i.e. `module load R/R-3.3.3`

Comment: See this answer for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654725/786542

Comment: I suggest this has much more to do with the batch system (and cluster) you have than on R itself. (Version problems can -- and do -- afflict other tools like python and even bash.) If you expand your online search to include topics other than the R programming language, I expect you would find more relevant information.

Comment: hi @Tung, its work for me... thanks